# TestNG XML execution order

Tags: testing, testng

I have testng java project as below (in the exact order)

```
TestNGOnePack
 ClassOne.java
 ClassTwo.java

TestNGThreePack
 ClassOne.java
 ClassTwo.java

TestNGTwoPack
 ClassOne.java
 ClassTwo.java
```

each java file is as follows

```
@Test
public void pkgName()
{
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
}
```

testng.xml is as follows

```
<suite name="Suite One">
<test name="Test One" >
<classes>
 <class name="TestNGTwoPack.ClassTwo" />   
 <class name="TestNGOnePack.ClassOne" />
</classes>
    <packages>
         <package name="TestNGThreePack" />
   </packages> 
</test>
```

when I ran this as testng I got the following output

```
TestNGTwoPack.ClassTwo
TestNGThreePack.ClassOne
TestNGOnePack.ClassOne
TestNGThreePack.ClassTwo
```

My question is the output's sequence is ambiguous
Shouldn't it be as follows? what wrong here ??? what's the reason that the output is as above and not as below ??

```
TestNGTwoPack.ClassTwo
TestNGOnePack.ClassOne
TestNGThreePack.ClassOne
TestNGThreePack.ClassTwo
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, **unfortunately what you see is the currently implemented behaviour** in testNG.

*See [this discussion](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/106) to stay up to date.*

#### Workaround

There are several methods to work around this issue, including groups and dependsOnGroups etc. that you can read about in the discussion above.

But in your case I think I would go for several suite-files and one **"Master-Suite"** that fires these suites, then you can be sure to have the right order of execution.

Your testng_packageAandB.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name="Suite - package A and B">
    <test name="Test - package A and B">
        <classes preserve-order="true">
            <class name="drkthng.selenium_experiments.packageB.Class01" />
            <class name="drkthng.selenium_experiments.packageA.Class02" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Your testng_packageC.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name="Suite - package C">
    <test name="Test - package C">
        <packages preserve-order="true">
            <package name="drkthng.selenium_experiments.packageC" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And your "run all" xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name="allSuites">
  <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="testng_packageAandB.xml" />
    <suite-file path="testng_packageC.xml" />
  </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Running only the last xml will give you an execution that you expect, in my case this one:

> [TestNG] Running:
>   D:\JavaWorkspace\selenium-experiments\testng_packageAandB.xml
>
> drkthng.selenium_experiments.packageB.Class01
>   drkthng.selenium_experiments.packageA.Class02
>
> [TestNG] Running:
>   D:\JavaWorkspace\selenium-experiments\testng_packageC.xml
>
> drkthng.selenium_experiments.packageC.Class01
>   drkthng.selenium_experiments.packageC.Class02

Comment: Ohk got it.. Thanks a lot.. !

Comment: That attribute preserve order does not work. It throws the exception "Attribute "preserve-order" must be declared for element type "classes".".

Comment: Note: if running the suites with maven, you don't need a "MasterSuite". You can simply specify each suite file in order, as part of failsafe plugin configuration in your pom. The xml path is `plugin.configuration.suiteXmlFiles.suiteXmlFile*`

Answer (score 0):

In the main xml order between the classes,
 if you need order inside the class set priority

on testng new version (6.14.*) it didnt work ,it work for me in tesng version 6.9.10

by package is not working :(

```
 <packages>
            <package name="com.a.automation.catedor.tests.Tests.*" />        
 </packages>    




    Main xml

    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="All" verbose="10" parallel="false">

        <suite-files>
            <suite-file path="A.xml"/>
            <suite-file path="B.xml"/>
            <suite-file path="C.xml"/>
        </suite-files>
    </suite>

    ---A.xml ---

     <test name="General">
                <groups>
                    <run>
                        <exclude name="ignore"/>
                    </run>
                </groups>
                <classes>

                    <class name="com.a.automation.tests.ws.Class1"/>
                    <class name="com.a.automation.tests.ws.Class2"/>


                </classes>
        </test>
```